# objects eligible for garbage collection in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Test
 {
  public static void main(String[] agrs)
   {


    String[] person = new String[20];

    String pername = "Peter";

    person[0] = pername;

    pername = null;

    System.out.println(person[0]);       // prints " Peter " on screen

    System.out.println(pername);       // no content in pername. prints " null "


   }

}
```

will the pername object eligible for garbage collection ?
i think its eligible because the person[0] contains " Peter " and person[0]  doesnt not refer pername anymore .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little misunderstanding here. `pername` or `person[0]` are just references to the actual instance of String object. Reference live on stack and will be on stack till it is in programs context. The String instance will not be GCed unless both references are null.

Any objects reachable from GC roots cannot be garbage collected. A simple java program will have following GC roots

1. Local variables in the main method
2. The main thread
3. Static variables of the main class

Your case falls under 1st category.

You can read more - [Java Memory Management](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx)

Comment: but pername has completed its job..it has nothing to do after assigning null to it

Comment: Yes I am saying it is just a reference. Both `pername ` and `person[0]` point to same String instance in the heap memory. Even if you have made `pername` point to null `person[0]` is still pointing to the original String instance and hence will not be gced. `pername ` reference will remain on stack till end of your main method. You can point it to some different String instance.

Comment: It will be garbage collected but you do not know when it happens because gc has it own algoritm and gc by the way is a quite complicated...

Comment: No object can be garbage collected until is is reachable from one of the GC roots and local variables are one of them. Read http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx

Comment: You cannot say `pername ` or `person[0]` can be GCed. Object living on heap can be GCed and it is just one String in your case and both references point to it. So you cannot say if reference is GCed or not. It is the String object that the reference points to that can be GCed and that will be GCed only when both references are null.

Comment: Nope, this falls under case (3). The string constant won't be eligible for garbage collection unless the class is unloaded.

Comment: Static variables of *any class* (unless that class is itself eligible for garbage collection, which can happen)

Comment: @chrylis Neither `person` nor `pername` are static fields... unless you're referring to the string interning system (which is too complicated to talk about here)?

Comment: @immibis The *object* referred to by both `pername` and `person[0]` is hard-referenced by the class itself from the class's constant table. It can be evicted from the intern pool, but only if the class is unloaded.

Comment: @chrylis Good point, I didn't think of the constant pool... but it's not exactly a static variable either. (Can it be treated as a member of the Class object?)